# Get previous and later line from a file

Tags: unix, grep

I use grep to find a line which is having my search characters. Along with that line I want previous line as well later line.

```
For example

cat test.csv

bbbbbbbbbbbbb
xxx234.123yyy
abc123.456efg
zzz789.222xxx
aaaaaaaaaaaaa

grep '123.456' test.csv

I get a line say,
abc123.456efg

Addition to that I need like this

xxx234.123yyy
abc123.456efg
zzz789.222xxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-A` and `-B` options:

```
% grep -A1 -B1 '123.456' test.csv
xxx234.123yyy
abc123.456efg
zzz789.222xxx
```

This prints one line of leading context and one line of trailing context.

As a shortcut, grep also provides the `-C` option which combines `-A` and `-B`:

```
% grep -C1 '123.456' test.csv
xxx234.123yyy
abc123.456efg
zzz789.222xxx
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -C 1 abc123 input
```

From man-page:

```
-C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
           Print NUM lines of output context
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where the `-C` flag is designed for

```
$ cat file
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
xxx234.123yyy
abc123.456efg
zzz789.222xxx
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
$ grep 123.456 file
abc123.456efg
$ grep -C1 123.456 file
xxx234.123yyy
abc123.456efg
zzz789.222xxx
```